# c++ winSock.Функция inet_addr(" ") ,что принимает?

Tags: c++, winapi, winsock

Мне нужно написать функцию создающую экземпляр SOCKADDR_IN.Но в эту функцию мне как-то надо передавать ip адресс. Чем это сделать?Массивом char?

```
SOCKADDR_IN *addresInit(?? ip)
{
    SOCKADDR_IN addr;
    int sizeofaddr = sizeof(addr);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
    addr.sin_port = htons(1111);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функция `inet_addr` принимает аргумент типа `char *`, представляющий собой указатель на нуль-терминированную строку, содержащую строковое представление ip-адреса.

Подробнее в [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-inet_addr).

Ваш код можно дополнить так:

```cpp
SOCKADDR_IN &addresInit(const char * ip)
{
    SOCKADDR_IN addr;
    int sizeofaddr = sizeof(addr);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
    addr.sin_port = htons(1111);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
}
```

`const` перед `char*` в объявлении типа аргумента функции означает, что Вы не собираетесь изменять его значение в теле этой функции.

Использовать как-то так:

```cpp
SOCKADDR_IN& sckaddr = addresInit("127.0.0.1"); // Адрес локалхоста взят только для примера, подойдёт любой IP
```

По просьбам страждущих добавляю ещё некоторые исправления в Ваш код:

```cpp
SOCKADDR_IN addresInit(const char * ip)
{
    SOCKADDR_IN addr;
    // (убрал, ибо не используется) int sizeofaddr = sizeof(addr);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
    addr.sin_port = htons(1111);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    return addr;
}
```

Негодование сообщества было вызвано тем, что Вы возвращали ссылку на переменную, созданную в теле функции. При выходе из функции эта переменная будет удалена, а ссылка станет указывать на "пустое место", что может привести к плохим последствиям.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Я прошу Вас заметить, что не я автор этого кода. Я лишь решил проблему, озвученную автором. Я не занимался инспекцией кода. У функции не было возвращаемого значения, я его добавил, не вдумываясь. Зря видно. Верну в первозданный вид.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Существует кнопка "править", где Вы, в случае нахождения ошибок в ответе, можете изменить его, не затронув общего смысла, вместо того, чтобы оставлять гневные комментарии по этому поводу.

Comment: @V-Mor раньше я так и делал - но как-то раз в ответ на меня столько оскорблений вылилось, что теперь я предпочитаю писать комментарии и ставить минусы...

Comment: @PavelMayorov Это, конечно, уже дело личное. Но я лично все оскорбления пропускаю мимо ушей (не забывая нажать при этом флажок, конечно же). А сам к такому поведению отнюдь не склонен.